# How can I set the background color of <option> in a <select> element?

Tags: html, select, background-color

How do you set the background color of an item in an HTML  list?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```css
select.list1 option.option2
{
    background-color: #007700;
}
```

```html
<select class="list1">
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2" class="option2">Option 2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: why use `>` ? `<option>` elements can only ever exist inside a select anyway

Comment: can you make text inside <option> **bold** also with css?

Comment: This solution still doesn't work in Chrome and Safari.

Comment: I would need to add the bg color programmatically, so, I can't really use classes. Something like this:
`
    try {
      opt_css.backgroundColor = item.color; // this might be not defined
      $opt.prop('disabled', item.disabled); // this too
    } catch(e) {
      // do nothing
    }
`
As a result, I can see "style" attribute added to the <option> tag, like this: `<option value="Status 1" style="padding: 2px; background-color: rgb(255, 204, 204);"> Status 1</option>`, but no visual color changes (Chrome @ Mac Os)

Answer (score 24):

I assume you mean the `<select>` input element?

Support for that is pretty new, but FF 3.6, Chrome and IE 8 render this all right:

```html
<select name="select">
  <option value="1" style="background-color: blue">Test</option>
  <option value="2" style="background-color: green">Test</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem too. I found setting the appearance to none helped.

```
.class {
    appearance:none;
    -moz-appearance:none;
    -webkit-appearance:none;

    background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like normal `background-color: #f0f`

You just need a way to target it, eg: `<option id="myPinkOption">blah</option>`