# Set background color for input field only Select Option list

Tags: html, css

There's a load of question about setting background colours for select lists,
eg. [HTML: how to set background color of item in select element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2789741/html-how-to-set-background-color-of-item-in-select-element)

However, my question is such:
Is it possible to set colour ONLY the input field, and no colours for the actual dropdown?

[image]

Comment: what do you actuallt want? please explain more.

Comment: can you show the code or what you have done so far?

Comment: You say 'Is it possible to set colour ONLY the input field` What input do you mean? You are talking about a select dropdown? I don't get it. Please explain more.

Comment: @scarecrow there's no relevant code to show. It's a question of whether it's possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this the result you are looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/A6C6W/

**HTML**

```
<select>
    <option>iygsdfiygsdfkasdf</option>
    <option>tbhvrthvrcegrtgc</option>
    <option>wevgergwvergvergver</option>
</select>
```

**CSS**

```
select{
    background: red;
}
select option{
    background: white;
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: yes, but is there no way to just set a background colour only for the input field, without the need to reset option to white?

Comment: thats the question i'm asking. :)

Comment: you should add "without giving a style to the <option>s tag" in the requirements then, because I missed that part :D

Comment: well at least you answered lol. going to accept your answer when they let me