# How do I specify the background colour in an HTML select using CSS (without using multiple)?

Tags: html, css, html-select, background-color

Does anyone know how to format HTML `select/option` lists *without* using `multiple`? I cannot get the CSS `background-color` to work at all. I have tried putting it on the `select`, I have tried putting it on the `option`, but nothing works.

(If I use `multiple`, then the formatting works, but I get other problems).

Comment: You mean the background of the "flyout" you get, when you open the select field? I don't think you can format that. You will need a custom solution to replace the native select field then, if this is really a requirement.

Comment: Yeah, I've never seen that done either. You'd have to do something cool and fancy to accomplish that I suspect. Interesting that he's got it working with `multiple` though.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I set the background color of <option> in a <select> element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2789741/how-can-i-set-the-background-color-of-option-in-a-select-element)

Comment: About `select` and `option` (and other inputs), each browser works differently (sadly). If you want full control over the design, you should build a custom solution with a bit of Javascript.